# Как залогиниться на яндексе с помощью Requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Решил спарсить wordstat.yandex.ru, столкнулся с проблемой, оказывается, только авторизованный пользователь может работать с вордстатом, всплывает модальное окно с input
Попробовал сделать так:

```
def request(url):
    headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    r = requests.Session().get(url, headers=headers, auth=('vasyanya123', '123456'))
    return r.text
```

Не работает. Наведите пожалуйста на решение

Answer (score 0):

Попробовал сделать авторизацию, заметил, что помимо логина и пароля отправляется параметр timestamp:1503609983121 (текущее время в unix + количество миллисекунд аля new Date().getTime() на JS), но мне выдает ошибку "Логин не указан", может, вы дальше продвинетесь.